# Cannot build P4Python without SSL support win 10

Tags: pip, perforce, p4python

trying to install p4python on Windows 10 with cmd:

```
pip install p4python
```

and getting

> Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/5a/0a1b192cdecd31cb8bc0d0ba39c73ffd84ce823053d0004823a1fdbe1440/p4python-2018.2.1743033.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Attempting to load API from ftp.perforce.com
>       Loaded API into None ... Cannot build P4Python without SSL support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a prebuilt version of p4python from here:

https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-core-api-python

Comment: I'm still having this error after an install of the package above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  Don't use pip to install p4python unless you have the necessary components to build p4python from source, including a working SSL library.  Instead, download the MSI from the link above and it should just work.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that P4Python will not work on any version of python.

The solution is to find a version that is supported by visiting https://pypi.org/project/p4python/#files

You should see the releases with suffixes like `cp39` indicating that the package supports python 3.9.x. As I write this, there is no package supporting python 3.10, so anyone trying `pip install p4python` on python 3.10.2 like I did will get this `Cannot build P4Python without SSL support` error along with the `Parameter --ssl is needed`.

Downgrading to python 3.9.10 solved the issue.

Comment: Very helpful! I was looking for a version that runs on Python 3.6 on Windows. In the [Download files](https://pypi.org/project/p4python/#files) tab, it only listed cp36 files for linux and mac. Going through the release history, I was able to find an [older version](https://pypi.org/project/p4python/2020.1.2056111/#files) that was also available for win64.