# How do I install p4python on macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, perforce, macos-catalina, p4python

I get an error when trying to install p4python on macOS 10.15 Catalina.
Command `pip install p4python`.

```
Cannot build P4Python without SSL support
Exception: Parameter –ssl is needed
```

When I try to install an older version, I also get an error.
Command `pip install p4python==2018.2.1743033`.

```
Cannot match OpenSSL Version string ‘LibreSSL 2.8.3’
Cannot build P4Python without SSL support
```

The second error seems to be caused by macOS using LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL.

Any ideas how to get it installed?

Comment: Did you read the first error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p4python can not be installed because it doesn't have a package for Python 3.8. 
Which is the Python 3 version installed by default. The latest release only has packages for Python up-to 3.7: [p4python 2019.1.1858212 PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/p4python/2019.1.1858212/#files)

I installed Python 3.7 with pyenv to get p4python installed/working.

```
// install pyenv and required python version
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.7

// add following to ~/.bash_profile
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv/shims"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/python"

// go to project directory and set python version
cd project
pyenv local 3.7.7
// check verion
python --version
// install p4python
pip install p4python
```

Old answer:

*Answer from Perforce Technical Support*

> *p4python is not supported on MacOS 10.15.2.*

Comment: Is there a link to this comment from Perforce? (I need to raise it with management…  )

Comment: It was a response on a support email, so no link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows and answered a similar question here: [Cannot build P4Python without SSL support win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687847/cannot-build-p4python-without-ssl-support-win-10)

I suspect the same answer applies to macosx:

The issue is that p4python is released for specific versions of python on windows and macosx. Look in https://pypi.org/project/p4python/#files and search for the "macosx". You will see `cpXY` in the filename, ex. `cp39` indicating that this package will work on python X.Y, ex. 3.9. Trying to install p4python on an unsupported version of python will result in this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing exactly what it's telling you to do?

`pip install p4python -ssl`

Comment: That seems to pass the option to pip and not to p4python. Output: `Usage: pip install [options] ... no such option: --ssl`

Comment: You might look at this answer then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677577/distutils-how-to-pass-a-user-defined-parameter-to-setup-py

Comment: Basically you're trying to run the setup.py and pass it the -ssl command: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4python/setup.py?v=7

Comment: You can either manually download the module and run the setup.py yourself or try to figure out how to pass an argument to setup.py via pip

Comment: I was able to pass the argument to setup.py via pip using following command: `pip install --install-option="--ssl" p4python`. But now I get the error `option --ssl not recognized` from setup.py.

Comment: According to the OP it only requires one dash before the `-ssl` : try `pip install --install-option="-ssl" p4python`

Comment: With `-ssl`as option the error `option -s not recognized` is returned. The script is checking for `if '--ssl' in sys.argv`.