# Python setuptools ssl install-option not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to install a library (p4python) with pip which requires to specify the **--ssl** option. 
Here is the command I run:

```
 pip install --install-option="--ssl" --install-option="/usr/local/ssl/lib/" p4python
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error: option --ssl not recognize
```

I don't understand. This should be a valid options for setup.py:
https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4python/setup.py?v=7 
I saw someone mentioning this issue in this post: 
[How do I install p4python on macOS 10.15 Catalina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372106/how-do-i-install-p4python-on-macos-10-15-catalina)

However, no one gave a solution for this problem.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In [p4python setup.py](https://github.com/perforce/p4python/blob/master/setup.py) the option `--ssl` is available for `setup.py` subcommands [`build`](https://github.com/perforce/p4python/blob/dd6d13e4d6f59dab50eba42a50087ed3e0d418bd/setup.py#L96), [`build_ext`](https://github.com/perforce/p4python/blob/dd6d13e4d6f59dab50eba42a50087ed3e0d418bd/setup.py#L120) and [`sdist`](https://github.com/perforce/p4python/blob/dd6d13e4d6f59dab50eba42a50087ed3e0d418bd/setup.py#L355). But not for `install` or `wheel`.

That is, you can run `python setup.py build --ssl` but I'm not sure you can do `python setup.py install --ssl`. And `pip install --install-option=--ssl` does exactly that.

So either you use `pip` to install a precompiled wheel ­— they provide [a lot](https://pypi.org/project/p4python/#files) but not for Python 3.8. Downgrade to Python 3.7.

Or you install from sources by downloading the sources, unpacking the archive and running

```
python setup.py build_ext --ssl /usr/local/ssl/lib/
python setup.py build --ssl /usr/local/ssl/lib/
python setup.py install
```